# Depth Shader bug in Android (Unity): artefacts and glitches in material

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, shader, mask

I had a problem with a simple shader made to Mobile Unity Project.

```
Shader "Custom/InvisibleMask" 
{
    SubShader
    {
        // draw after all opaque objects (queue = 2001):
        Tags { "Queue" = "Geometry+1" }
        Pass 
        {
          Blend Zero One // keep the image behind it
        }
    }

    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

This shader only hide GameObject with RenderQueue greater than "Geometry+1" and show GameObjects less than "Geometry+1". The below image show the glitches on top and bottom of the fridge.

[image]

For some strange reason this shader is not working on some android devices like the Moto G5 and Moto G5 Plus.

I am using Unity 2019.2.15.

Answer (score 2):

I searched a lot for the solution of this bug on the internet but I couldn't find someone who had the same problem. I had to go testing different configurations until I could find the problem. I discovered that the problem is a failure in the integration of Unity with the Vulkan API or simply a failure of the Vulkan API.

To solve the problem, just go to the Android project settings and remove the Vulkan graphics API.

Comment: Project Settings->Player->Other Settings

Auto Graphics API: uncheck

In Graphics API list, remove Vulkan.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had plane mesh that was water. It was very large.
After I reduced its size the problem seem to go away.